# Specify container deployment target with Kubernetes, e.g. Test/Production

Tags: azure, docker, coreos, kubernetes

Based on the following setup of Kubernetes on [Microsoft Azure](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure).

I was able to deploy my Docker containers, using the same configuration settings.

We have 2 categories of containers, front-end and back-end, where the back-end consist of high intensive processing. The latter we want to run on Large instances, whereas the front-end will be run on Small instances.

What is the best option to separate these, my gues would be with labeling the hosts. But was not able to find this in the docs, or in examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, adding labels to the hosts and restricting your pods to nodes with the appropriate label (e.g. 'Large' / 'Small') is the best way to do this. For an example, see [examples/node-selection](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/node-selection)

Kubernetes has a [resource model](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/resources.md) which, once implemented, will allow you to tell the scheduler what resources each pod needs and the system will ensure that the pod is placed on a node with available resources. Unfortunately, as you can tell from the design document on Github, this isn't fully implemented yet.

Comment: Please can you provide a sample how to restrict pods to nodes?

Comment: See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/node-selection